# failed linking file resources and AAPT2 error

Tags: android

Im trying to design navigation drawer in my android application.
The file (drawer_activity.xml) is the navigation pane. 
i have created another file (activity_main_drawer.xml)
In that file,i have put all the options which i'm going to show in navigation pane.
Below is the (drawer_activity.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Below is the code for (activity_main_drawer.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
 <item android:title="@string/help_support">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/contact_us"
                android:title="@string/contact_us" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/terms_conditions"
                android:title="@string/terms_conditions" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/help_center"
                android:title="@string/help_center" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Below is the string resource file for the items in navigation pane:

```
<resource>
 <!-- navigation_bar support and details -->
    <string name="help_support">Help and Support</string>
    <string name="contact_us">Contact Us</string>
    <string name="terms_conditions">Terms and Conditions</string>
    <string name="help_center">Help Center</string>
</resource>
```

The errors which im getting are as follows:

```
 Error:error: resource string/help_support (aka com.pravesh.myapplication:string/help_support) not found.
    Error:error: resource string/contact_us (aka com.pravesh.myapplication`string/contact_us) not found.
    Error:error: resource string/terms_conditions (aka com.pravesh.myapplication:string/terms_conditions) not found.
    Error:error: resource string/help_center (aka com.pravesh.myapplication:string/help_center) not found.
    Error:resource string/help_support (aka com.pravesh.myapplication:string/help_support) not found.
    Error:resource string/contact_us (aka com.pravesh.myapplication:string/contact_us) not found.
    Error:resource string/terms_conditions (aka com.pravesh.myapplication:string/terms_conditions) not found.
    Error:resource string/help_center (aka com.pravesh.myapplication:string/help_center) not found.
    Error:failed linking file resources.
    Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: `AAPT2 error: check logs for details` . might mean there are more logs that will help point out the error. can you scan for that and add the relevant parts to to the question?

Comment: do you mean event log? im a beginner.

Comment: yep,  I think there might be more information about what went wrong than what you have for **The errors which im getting are as follows** area (either above or below these lines)

Comment: at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
 at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
 at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
 at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

Comment: Where is the file with the strings located? Is it in app/src/main/res/values/<name>.xml?

Comment: Maybe you can also create a small repro project and post a link to it?